# reshape data size matlab

Tags: matlab, reshape

i designed a Neural Network with 784 (28*28) neuron . my input data is Arabic Number from 0~9 . if the data size be 784 my program will work and guess the number with my algorithm . but when the size of input data be more than 784 will get me error about size of input . my code is :

```
image=imresize(imread(strcat(filepath, filename)),[28,28]);
Data_test=[]
Data_test{1}=[image];
Data_test{2}=[image];
Data_test{3}=[image];
Data_test{4}=[image];
Data_test=Data_test'
labels_test=[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]];
labels_test=labels_test'
size1=[28 28];

% while size(Data_test_reshaped) < [28 28 ]
   [Data_test_reshaped] = Resize_Reshape_Data(Data_test,size1); 
% end
```

i wrote a while for that

> continue reshaping until size of my input be less or equal [28 28 ]

.

but i dont know why the code didnt work for size of more than 784 . i dont know how can i reshape it to [28 28 ]

what should i do my mates ? whats your idea ?

Thanks for helping  me